# How to make recursive django admin inline relationships?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

I need to create an arbitrarily deep modular structure using Django admin. The [nested_admin package](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin) has gotten me part of the way there, but there's a key piece of functionality that's still eluding me — the ability to create an object B inline off object A and then create another object A off that instance of object B. Here's a closer look at my models (simplified):

```py
class ChatConditional(models.Model):
    triggering_question = models.ForeignKey(
        'texts.MessageChain',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    keyword_response = models.ForeignKey(
        'texts.MessageChain',
        related_name='keyword_answer',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

class MessageChain(models.Model):
    conditional_trigger = models.ForeignKey(
        'texts.ChatConditional',
        blank=True, null=True,
    )
    message = models.TextField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True)
```

So in the admin, I want to be able to create a ChatConditional to serve as a response to a certain MessageChain. Then once I create that Conditional, create another MessageChain to send that will potentially link to another Conditional. Here's what my admin models look like:

```py
class SMSConditionalAdmin(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = ChatConditional
    extra = 0
    fk_name = "triggering_question"
    inlines = [SMSChainAdmin]

class SMSChainAdmin(nested_admin.NestedStackedInline):
    model = MessageChain
    extra = 0
    inlines = [SMSConditionalAdmin]
```

And now you can likely see the problem: In order to fully define the SMSConditionalAdmin, I need to set up an inline relationship to SMSChainAdmin, and vice versa. I might be missing something obvious, but how can I work around this need for the two admin inlines to recursively refer to one another?

Thanks in advance!